# How to get a json subclass with python

Tags: python, json, subclass

i have the following json file, the "ticket" python variable contains the "data" part:

```
{
"date": "139096543" 
"data": [
    {
    "author": {
                "title": "User",
                "champion": false,
                "canonical_name": "tahlia_moffitt",
                "id": 6944932
    },
    "is_spam": false,
    "me_too_count": 2,
    "status": "complete"
    }
]
}
```

I used the following python script to get the data for example from "status":

```
'status': ticket.get('status') or 'NoStatus'
```

But i need the data from the author subclass. I tried as:

```
'title': ticket.get('author.title') or 'NoTitle'
```

and

```
'title': ticket.get('author[title]') or 'NoTitle'
```

too, but they didnt work for me. Can anybody propose a solution for me?

Comment: That's not really an appropriate use of *"subclass"*, which implies inheritance.

Comment: I'm still looking for the closing `]`. I hope this is not your real json file, as it seems improperly formatted.

Comment: @Flav yes i only tried to cut a sample from to json which explain my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this construction:

```
'title': ticket.get('author',{}).get(title', 'NoTitle')
```

Construction

```
get(title', 'NoTitle')
```

Will return value if present, if not will return second value.

Comment: Thank you it worked! Is the " get(title', 'NoTitle') " construction better then the " get('title') or 'NoTitle' " ?

Comment: Not exactly shorter, but tells you what you want to do:) It's a getter from a dict, with a default value.